# Conditional Flag/event marker in highchart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm looking for a conditional based flag marker upon an event in **highcharts**.
**WHAT EXACTLY I"M DOING:** Getting data from CSV and rendering the chart, incase if it goes beyond particular value, then I need to flag those events so that users can easily see in a big range.

Ex: In this case, the data is loaded from CSV, and have to mark the events which are gone beyon 75
http://www.highcharts.com/studies/data-from-csv.htm
as like this http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/flags-general. I have tried with the other reference/example. But those are using static/hard coded in the jQuery, those are not using conditional based flags.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning flags are available only in the highstock.js. You need to add additonal serie with this type, in example in callback (addSeries method).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution which i have tried is ,Create a data element on javascript side and add all those points which exceeds the threshold into it.

Create a flag series

```
        {
            useHTML:true,
            type : 'flags',
            data : myflagsData,
            shape : 'circle',
            color : 'black',
            stackDistance : 120,
            textAlign: 'center',
            showInLegend : false
    }
```

Add new exceeded data to this series .
You will have to add hisghstock.js .But you can still use highCharts with this js . Use Highcharts.Chart while creating the chart.